# Codeigniter index.php not executing

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I have a fresh install of codeigniter on ubuntu but when I go to **localhost/codeigniter**  this simply opens the **index.php** file's code.
I am not getting any welcome message of codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed php?
If you are using apache have you installed libapache2-mod-php5 ?